# php code not being interpreted over ssl

Tags: apache-2.2, php

using centos OS and apache 2.2.3

my php code is not interpreted over ssl.  It renders out the code within the browser.  Page works fine under http.

Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost secure.cognitionsmartsites.com:443> 
  AddType text/html .php 
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php 
  ServerName secure.cognitionsmartsites.com 
  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs"> 
    Allow from all Options +Indexes 
  </Directory> 
  IndexOptions 
  ServerAlias secure.cognitionsmartsites.com 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs 
  SSLEngine On 
  SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert.crt 
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/private.key 
  SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/intermediate.crt 
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd -S output

```
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.0.1:80         siteeditor.vserver.onlinehome-server.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz011_siteeditor.conf:8)
127.0.0.1:80           siteeditor.vserver.onlinehome-server.info (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz011_siteeditor.conf:8)
74.208.101.55:80       default (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz010_psa_httpd.conf:48)
74.208.101.55:443      secure.cognitionsmartsites.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/smartsitessl.conf:3)

wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          s15441819.onlinehome-server.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
default server s361865982.onlinehome.us (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:989)
port 80 namevhost s361865982.onlinehome.us (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:989)

Syntax OK
```

One other thing is that I can browse to image files under https and they render fine.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your apache vhost config

Comment: <VirtualHost secure.cognitionsmartsites.com:443>
AddType text/html .php 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
ServerName secure.cognitionsmartsites.com
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs">
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
IndexOptions
ServerAlias  secure.cognitionsmartsites.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Thanks for adding the config! Next time it'd be great if you could edit the question instead of pasting it in a comment. I'm fixing it for you now, so hopefully you'll get help quicker.

Comment: my bad..will edit better from here on out

Comment: what is the output of "httpd -S"?

Comment: You should normally not have to specifically enable php in your virtual host. And compare your zz010_pas_httpd.conf with your smartsitessl.conf.

Comment: thanks...checked that other conf file and php engine was set to "off"...much appreciated

Comment: Hi ->  AddType text/html .php  <- thats your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove:

```
AddType text/html .php
```

Since your php files are php files and not plain content